# Workflow to alert of multiple documents uploaded

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer

Good Afternoon.  I am trying to create a SharePoint 2013 Workflow that scans a document library once a day and sends an email with a list of documents modified in that library.

I am struggling in outputting the list of documents into the send email function in SharePoint Designer.

this is similar functionality to the alerts,  but I need to be able to control the verbiage in the mail sent.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably going to have to use SharePoint 2013 workflow here. That way you can work with collections and HTTP calls since the list of documents will be in a collection that you can loop through and parse out, SharePoint Designer's dictionary actions are your match.

I would use REST in order to retreive the documents:

```
http://sharepoint/_api/subsite/web/lists/GetByTitle('Shared Documents')/items?$filter=Modified ge [Today]
```

Put that into a dictionary and loop through it to create your HTML table that you can store in a string and send in an email:

```
Loop (count of dictionary) times
Get "Title" from VariableDictionary (output TitleVar)
Get "Modified" from VariableDictionary (output ModifiedByVar)
Set Workflow Variable [Variable:EmailString] to: 

   [Variable:EmailString]
   TitleVar | ModifiedVar |
```

This is a good blog that explains it: http://blog.vgrem.com/2014/05/08/consuming-the-sharepoint-2013-rest-service-from-sharepoint-designer/

Comment: Mike,  this has definitely got me in the write direction,  but Im not getting the sytax for [Today] to work as today date. Any ideas?

Comment: At the beginning of your workflow, set a new workflow variable (as a DateTime) and set it to Today, then use that workflow variable instead.